# Can't determine why inputs.mqtt_consumer is disconnecting and not sending data to influxdb via telegraf

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

i m using mqtt, telegraf and influxdb.
telegraf and influxdb are installed and works fine
i can execute the command mosquitto_sub ... and i get my data
but when i try to use inputs.mqtt_consumer on telegraf config, i get nothing and its disconnects so quickly from the server.
here is my telegraf conf

> ## Telegraf Configuration

```
# Telegraf is entirely plugin driven. All metrics are gathered from the
# declared inputs, and sent to the declared outputs.
#
# Plugins must be declared in here to be active.
# To deactivate a plugin, comment out the name and any variables.
#
# Use 'telegraf -config telegraf.conf -test' to see what metrics a config
# file would generate.
#
# Environment variables can be used anywhere in this config file, simply surround
# them with ${}. For strings the variable must be within quotes (ie, "${STR_VAR}"),
# for numbers and booleans they should be plain (ie, ${INT_VAR}, ${BOOL_VAR})


# Global tags can be specified here in key="value" format.
[global_tags]
  # dc = "us-east-1" # will tag all metrics with dc=us-east-1
  # rack = "1a"
  ## Environment variables can be used as tags, and throughout the config file
  # user = "$USER"


# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## Default data collection interval for all inputs
  interval = "20s"
  ## Rounds collection interval to 'interval'
  ## ie, if interval="10s" then always collect on :00, :10, :20, etc.
  round_interval = true

  ## Telegraf will send metrics to outputs in batches of at most
  ## metric_batch_size metrics.
  ## This controls the size of writes that Telegraf sends to output plugins.
  metric_batch_size = 1000

  ## Maximum number of unwritten metrics per output.  Increasing this value
  ## allows for longer periods of output downtime without dropping metrics at the
  ## cost of higher maximum memory usage.
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000

  ## Collection jitter is used to jitter the collection by a random amount.
  ## Each plugin will sleep for a random time within jitter before collecting.
  ## This can be used to avoid many plugins querying things like sysfs at the
  ## same time, which can have a measurable effect on the system.
  collection_jitter = "0s"

  ## Default flushing interval for all outputs. Maximum flush_interval will be
  ## flush_interval + flush_jitter
  flush_interval = "10s"
  ## Jitter the flush interval by a random amount. This is primarily to avoid
  ## large write spikes for users running a large number of telegraf instances.
  ## ie, a jitter of 5s and interval 10s means flushes will happen every 10-15s
  flush_jitter = "0s"

  ## By default or when set to "0s", precision will be set to the same
  ## timestamp order as the collection interval, with the maximum being 1s.
  ##   ie, when interval = "10s", precision will be "1s"
  ##       when interval = "250ms", precision will be "1ms"
  ## Precision will NOT be used for service inputs. It is up to each individual
  ## service input to set the timestamp at the appropriate precision.
  ## Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s".
  precision = ""

  ## Log at debug level.
    debug = true
  ## Log only error level messages.
  # quiet = false

  ## Log target controls the destination for logs and can be one of "file",
  ## "stderr" or, on Windows, "eventlog".  When set to "file", the output file
  ## is determined by the "logfile" setting.
  # logtarget = "file"

  ## Name of the file to be logged to when using the "file" logtarget.  If set to
  ## the empty string then logs are written to stderr.
   logfile = "log"

  ## The logfile will be rotated after the time interval specified.  When set
  ## to 0 no time based rotation is performed.  Logs are rotated only when
  ## written to, if there is no log activity rotation may be delayed.
  # logfile_rotation_interval = "0d"

  ## The logfile will be rotated when it becomes larger than the specified
  ## size.  When set to 0 no size based rotation is performed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_size = "0MB"

  ## Maximum number of rotated archives to keep, any older logs are deleted.
  ## If set to -1, no archives are removed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_archives = 5

  ## Override default hostname, if empty use os.Hostname()
  hostname = ""
  ## If set to true, do no set the "host" tag in the telegraf agent.
  omit_hostname = false


###############################################################################
#                            OUTPUT PLUGINS                                   #
###############################################################################


# Configuration for sending metrics to InfluxDB
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  ## The full HTTP or UDP URL for your InfluxDB instance.
  ##
  ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
  ## urls will be written to each interval.
  # urls = ["unix:///var/run/influxdb.sock"]
  # urls = ["udp://127.0.0.1:8089"]
   urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]

  ## The target database for metrics; will be created as needed.
  ## For UDP url endpoint database needs to be configured on server side.
   database = "telegraf"

  ## The value of this tag will be used to determine the database.  If this
  ## tag is not set the 'database' option is used as the default.
   database_tag = "telegraf"

  ## If true, the 'database_tag' will not be included in the written metric.
  # exclude_database_tag = false

  ## If true, no CREATE DATABASE queries will be sent.  Set to true when using
  ## Telegraf with a user without permissions to create databases or when the
  ## database already exists.
  # skip_database_creation = false

  ## Name of existing retention policy to write to.  Empty string writes to
  ## the default retention policy.  Only takes effect when using HTTP.
  # retention_policy = ""

  ## The value of this tag will be used to determine the retention policy.  If this
  ## tag is not set the 'retention_policy' option is used as the default.
   retention_policy_tag = ""

  ## If true, the 'retention_policy_tag' will not be included in the written metric.
  # exclude_retention_policy_tag = false

  ## Write consistency (clusters only), can be: "any", "one", "quorum", "all".
  ## Only takes effect when using HTTP.
  # write_consistency = "any"

  ## Timeout for HTTP messages.
   timeout = "60s"

  ## HTTP Basic Auth
   username = "admin1"
   password = "admin"

  ## HTTP User-Agent
   user_agent = "telegraf"

  ## UDP payload size is the maximum packet size to send.
  # udp_payload = "512B"

  ## Optional TLS Config for use on HTTP connections.
  # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
  # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
  # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false

  ## HTTP Proxy override, if unset values the standard proxy environment
  ## variables are consulted to determine which proxy, if any, should be used.
  # http_proxy = "http://corporate.proxy:3128"

  ## Additional HTTP headers
  # http_headers = {"X-Special-Header" = "Special-Value"}

  ## HTTP Content-Encoding for write request body, can be set to "gzip" to
  ## compress body or "identity" to apply no encoding.
  # content_encoding = "identity"

  ## When true, Telegraf will output unsigned integers as unsigned values,
  ## i.e.: "42u".  You will need a version of InfluxDB supporting unsigned
  ## integer values.  Enabling this option will result in field type errors if
  ## existing data has been written.
  # influx_uint_support = false

# # Configuration for sending metrics to InfluxDB

[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"]
  name_override = "mqtt_consumer_floats"
  topics =  ["/emonpi/current1"]
  connection_timeout = "120s"
  username = "emonpi"
  password = "******"
  data_format = "value"
  data_type = "float"
```

and here is the log from telegraf

```
  2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! Loaded inputs: mqtt_consumer win_perf_counters
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! Loaded aggregators: 
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! Loaded processors: 
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! Loaded outputs: influxdb
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! Tags enabled: host=win7-PC
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"win7-PC", Flush Interval:10s
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z D! [agent] Initializing plugins
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z D! [agent] Connecting outputs
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z D! [agent] Attempting connection to [outputs.influxdb]
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z D! [agent] Successfully connected to outputs.influxdb
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z D! [agent] Starting service inputs
2020-06-16T13:30:19Z I! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
2020-06-16T13:30:30Z D! [outputs.influxdb] Wrote batch of 103 metrics in 230.0132ms
2020-06-16T13:30:30Z D! [outputs.influxdb] Buffer fullness: 103 / 10000 metrics

2020-06-16T13:37:43Z D! [agent] Stopping service inputs
2020-06-16T13:37:43Z D! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Disconnecting [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
2020-06-16T13:37:43Z D! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Disconnected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]

2020-06-16T15:28:59Z D! [agent] Initializing plugins
2020-06-16T15:28:59Z D! [agent] Starting service inputs
2020-06-16T15:28:59Z I! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
2020-06-16T15:29:01Z D! [agent] Waiting for service inputs
2020-06-16T15:29:01Z D! [agent] Stopping service inputs
2020-06-16T15:29:01Z D! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Disconnecting [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
2020-06-16T15:29:01Z D! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Disconnected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
```

and i m not getting any creation of database in influxdb

pls help if there's something i m missing

Comment: ``# skip_database_creation = false`` -- doesn't that have to be set to true if your database does not already exist?  You also have a leading '/' on your MQTT topic.  Most programs can handle it, but some have problems with it as it is not a 'Best Practice' to have a leading slash in the Topic field.

Comment: i tried to uncomment it and i changed the topic but it still doesn't work, thank u very much for ur help